# Header 100% width with viewport scrolling content

Tags: css, dom, layout

I want to expand header and footer to 100% with the variable middle content width.

you can find the source at http://jsfiddle.net/9dWcZ/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
this is header
</div>

<div class="content">
  this is content
</div>

<div class="footer">
this is footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header, .footer {
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
.content {
    width:2500px;
    height:100px;
    background:#9B191B;
    float:left;
}
```

I don't want fixed header and no change in structure..

Please help..

thanks,

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  Can you explain how `.content` is suppose to display?

Comment: you have specified the content width to 2500px. Is that fixed, or can be dynamic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this layout as follows.

You need to add a `.wrapper` element, this is essential:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">this is header</div>
    <div class="content">this is content</div>
    <div class="footer">this is footer</div>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}
.header, .footer {
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
    height:200px;
}
.content {
    width:2500px;
    height:100px;
    background:#9B191B;
}
```

The key is to apply `display: table` to the `.wrapper` block.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7jxLC/

Answer (score 0):

So you want to expand it starting from the middle point?
If that's what you want you can use:
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
It will start to grow in width from the center then.

Comment: No, Actually I want to expend header bg to expend with the width of the middle content.. i.e. middle red bg is width is more so it is scorlling.. and header and footer are not scrolling.. as you see in jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9dWcZ/) http://jsfiddle.net/9dWcZ/